# Getting a Runtime Error in Executable made with pyinstaller

Tags: python, pygame, pyinstaller

So I have made a game using Pygame, and now I want to make a executable out of it(standalone executable is preferred). So I used this to make the executable:

```
pyinstaller --onefile main.py
```

The compiling goes well but I get a error while running it. This is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 15, in <module>
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not BytesIO
[5604] Failed to execute script 'main' due to unhandled exception!
```

I have a few image and sound files that I use with pygame and I suppose they are creating the issue.
This is my main.py file.:

```
import pygame as pg
import random
import time
import pygame.time
from pygame import mixer

pg.init()

pg.display.set_caption('Space Invaders')
icon = pg.image.load('001-ufo.png')
pg.display.set_icon(icon)
mixer.music.load('Tetris.mp3')
mixer.music.play(-1)
kills = 0
font = pg.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf', 34)


def Score():
    global kills
    score = font.render(f'Score: {kills}', True, (255, 000, 000))
    screen.blit(score, (10, 10))


class Vector:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = None
        self.y = None


class Bullet(pg.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        super().__init__()
        self.image = pg.image.load('bullet.png')
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.position = Vector()
        self.velocity = Vector()
        self.position.x = x
        self.position.y = y
        self.velocity.x = 0
        self.velocity.y = 5
        self.rect.center = [self.position.x, self.position.y]
        self.fire_sound = mixer.Sound('rocket_sound.wav')
        self.explosion_sound = mixer.Sound('explosion.wav')

    def update(self):
        self.position.y = self.position.y - self.velocity.y
        if self.position.y < -16:
            self.kill()
        self.rect.center = [self.position.x, self.position.y]
        new = pg.sprite.groupcollide(bullet_group, enemy_group, True, True)
        if new != {}:
            enemy = Enemy()
            enemy_group.add(enemy)
            self.explosion_sound.play()


class Player(pg.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.image = pg.image.load('player.png')
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.position = Vector()
        self.velocity = Vector()
        self.position.x = 650
        self.position.y = 600
        self.velocity.x = 0
        self.velocity.y = 0
        self.rect.center = [self.position.x, self.position.y]

    def update(self):
        self.position.x = self.position.x + self.velocity.x
        if self.position.x+32 > 1300:
            self.velocity.x = 0
            self.position.x = 1300-32
        if self.position.x-32 < 0:
            self.velocity.x = 0
            self.position.x = 0+32
        self.rect.center = [self.position.x, self.position.y]

    def create_bullet(self):
        return Bullet(self.position.x, self.position.y)


class Enemy(pg.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.position = Vector()
        self.velocity = Vector()
        self.image = pg.image.load('001-ufo.png')
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.position.y = random.randint(32, 368)
        self.position.x = random.randint(32, 1284)
        self.velocity.x = 5
        self.velocity.y = 0
        self.rect.center = [self.position.x, self.position.y]

    def update(self):
        self.position.x = self.position.x + self.velocity.x
        if self.position.x > 1284:
            self.position.x = 1284
            self.velocity.x = -5
            self.position.y += 32
        if self.position.x < 16:
            self.position.x = 16
            self.velocity.x = 5
            self.position.y += 32
        if self.position.y > 600-16:
            quit(0)
        self.rect.center = [self.position.x, self.position.y]


p1 = Player()
p_g = pg.sprite.Group()
p_g.add(p1)

bullet_group = pg.sprite.Group()

enemy_group = pg.sprite.Group()
for i in range(20):
    enemy = Enemy()
    enemy_group.add(enemy)

img = pg.image.load('player.png')
screen = pg.display.set_mode((1300, 700))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
prev_time = time.time()
running = True
while running:
    screen.fill((0, 255, 0))
    for event in pg.event.get():
        if event.type == pg.QUIT:
            quit(0)
        if event.type == pg.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pg.K_LEFT:
                p1.velocity.x = -10
            if event.key == pg.K_RIGHT:
                p1.velocity.x = 10
            if event.key == pg.K_SPACE:
                now_time = time.time()
                if now_time - prev_time > 0.5:
                    bullet = p1.create_bullet()
                    bullet_group.add(bullet)
                    bullet.fire_sound.play()
                    prev_time = now_time
        if event.type == pg.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pg.K_LEFT or event.key == pg.K_RIGHT:
                p1.velocity.x = 0

    p_g.update()
    p_g.draw(screen)

    bullet_group.update()
    bullet_group.draw(screen)
    enemy_group.update()
    enemy_group.draw(screen)
    pg.display.update()
    clock.tick(60)
```

These are my image and sound files. (ignore mainbak.py its just a backup file)
[image]

P.S. My game runs fine in python. The problem is only with the executable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a bug in pygame.

Reported in https://github.com/pygame/pygame/issues/2603, fixed in https://github.com/pygame/pygame/pull/2604

This will be fixed in pygame 2.0.2, whenever it comes out.

Edit: It was still broken for onefile executables, should be fixed by https://github.com/pygame/pygame/pull/2911, available in pygame 2.1.3.dev2. However, it broke again for a completely different reason (https://github.com/pygame/pygame/issues/3070) in the same release. So no current version works with this, at time of writing.

To mitigate this, you have to include a font file in your project, and not rely on the pygame default font. Many ttf files are available for download from Google Fonts.

Comment: I deleted the Score function and the font because i had not implemented it yet. Now it gives me a FileNotFoundError.
```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 10, in <module>
FileNotFoundError: No such file or directory.
[8104] Failed to execute script 'main' due to unhandled exception!
```

Comment: Yeah, you need to bundle data like images and sounds. Any file that your program loads needs to be bundled. It's a bit much to explain in a comment, but here is the relevant section in the Pyinstaller docs: https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/spec-files.html#adding-data-files

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem with pyinstaller when using --onflie and --adddata. You have to use a function in your code to find the path of your data.
There is a post where this is explained in detail.
[Bundling data files with PyInstaller (--onefile)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674790/bundling-data-files-with-pyinstaller-onefile/13790741#13790741)