# what is Not BytesIO?

Tags: python, pygame

I'm kind of new to this site and pygame and I was hoping for a bit of help. So I made this space invader clone which is about 180 lines right, when I run it on Pycharm, it works fine. So I decided to try testing it out further and tried converting it into an .exe file which is where my troubles began. Every time I try running the .exe, this message appears

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 62, in <module>
    font = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf',32)
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not BytesIO
```

I used freeCodeCamp.org's template and applied my own customs, here's a video incase you're interested: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FfWpgLFMI7w&t=7041s

Here's the code as well:

```
import math
import random

import pygame
from pygame import mixer

# Initialize the pygame
pygame.init()

# Create the screen
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((600, 400))



# Background Sound

mixer.music.load('Here he comes.mp3')
mixer.music.play(-1)



# Title and icon
pygame.display.set_caption("Defender of The Blue")
icon = pygame.image.load("Submarine of Vengeance.png")
pygame.display.set_icon(icon)

# Player
playerImg = pygame.image.load('Protagonist.png')
playerX = 250
playerY = 300
playerX_change = 0

# Enemy
enemyImg = []
enemyX = []
enemyY = []
enemyX_change = []
enemyY_change = []
num_of_enemies = 6

for i in range(num_of_enemies):
    enemyImg.append(pygame.image.load('Antagonist.png'))
    enemyX.append(random.randint(0, 500))
    enemyY.append(random.randint(10, 100))
    enemyX_change.append(0.1)
    enemyY_change.append(20)

# Energy Blast

# Ready - You can't see the bullet state on the screen
# Fire - The blast is currently moving
energyblastImg = pygame.image.load('energy-blasts.png')
energyblastX = 0
energyblastY = 300
energyblastX_change = 0
energyblastY_change = 1
energyblast_state = "ready"

# score

score_value = 0
font = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf',32)
textX = 10
textY = 10
game_over_font = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf',50)
# Game Over Text

def show_score(x,y):
    score = font.render("Score :" + str(score_value),True, (250,100,0))
    screen.blit(score, (x, y))

def game_over_text():
    game_over_text = game_over_font.render("GAME OVER",True, (250,0,0))
    screen.blit(game_over_text, (150, 100))


def player(x, y):
    screen.blit(playerImg, (x, y))


def enemy(x, y, i):
    screen.blit(enemyImg[i], (x, y))


def fire_energyblast(x, y):
    global energyblast_state
    energyblast_state = "fire"
    screen.blit(energyblastImg, (x + -1, y + 10))


def isCollison(enemyX, enemyY, energyblastX, energyblastY):
    distance = math.sqrt((math.pow(enemyX - energyblastX, 2)) + (math.pow(enemyY - energyblastY, 2)))
    if distance < 27:
        return True
    else:
        return False


# Game Loop
running = True
while running:

    # RGB = Red, Green, Blue
    screen.fill((0, 0, 128))

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

        # if keystroke is pressed check whether its right or left
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                playerX_change = -1
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                playerX_change = 1
            if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                if energyblast_state is "ready":
                    energyblast_sound = mixer.Sound('Energy Blast.mp3')
                    energyblast_sound.play()
                    # Get the current x coordinate of the submarine
                    energyblastX = playerX
                    fire_energyblast(energyblastX, energyblastY)

        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT or event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                playerX_change = 0

    # 5 = 5 + -0.1 -> 5 = 5 - 0.1
    # 5 = 5 + 0.1

    # Checking for boundaries of submarine so it doesn't go out of bounds
    playerX += playerX_change

    if playerX <= 0:
        playerX = 0
    elif playerX >= 500:
        playerX = 500

    # enemy movement
    for i in range(num_of_enemies):
        # Game Over
        if enemyY[i] > 272:
            for j in range(num_of_enemies):
                enemyY[j] = 2000
            game_over_text()
            break
        enemyX[i] += enemyX_change[i]
        if enemyX[i] <= 0:
            enemyX_change[i] = 1
            enemyY[i] += enemyY_change[i]
        elif enemyX[i] >= 500:
            enemyX_change[i] = -1
            enemyY[i] += enemyY_change[i]

        # Collision
        collison = isCollison(enemyX[i], enemyY[i], energyblastX, energyblastY)
        if collison:
            explosion_Sound = mixer.Sound('Explode.mp3')
            explosion_Sound.play()
            energyblastY = 300
            energyblast_state = "ready"
            score_value += 50
            enemyX[i] = random.randint(0, 500)
            enemyY[i] = random.randint(10, 100)

        enemy(enemyX[i],enemyY[i], i)

    # energy blast movement
    if energyblastY <= 0:
        energyblastY = 300
        energyblast_state = "ready"

    if energyblast_state is "fire":
        fire_energyblast(energyblastX, energyblastY)
        energyblastY -= energyblastY_change


    player(playerX, playerY)
    show_score(textX,textY)
    pygame.display.update()
```

I'm not quite sure what BytesIO is. Is it like having something used twice and cancels out? How can I change this?

Comment: Possible dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68737639/getting-a-runtime-error-in-executable-made-with-pyinstaller What's your pygame version?

Comment: Also, are you sure that the `freesansbold.ttf` file exists in the same directory?

Comment: Hey, author of the solution to that linked problem. This is definitely a duplicate of that, however my answer is a bit out of date, I’ll update it with more current info. @SuperStormer freesansbold.ttf is a special case, it creates an instance of the pygame default font, the file is stored inside the pygame library.

Comment: The version I use is 2.1.2

Comment: So should I replace the freesansbold with another font or is this not the problem?

Comment: Okay, I was wrong on the other issue (I've updated it once again). This is broken in every release, even the development pre releases of 2.1.3. But it's fixed on pygame-main, so it will be fixed whenever the next release is. My advice is to use a custom font, rather than the built in one. @GageK150

Answer (score 0):

Are you certain that "freesansbold.ttf" is downloaded and in the same directory as the code youre trying to run, if this isnt possible for whatever reason you should be able to replace the

```
font = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf',32)
```

with

```
font = pygame.font.Font('(file path)freesansbold.ttf',32)
```